# Как настроить свайп в плагине Slick?

Tags: javascript

Есть три слайдера (slick), эти 3 слайдера находятся в одном и при свайпе у меня меняются слайдеры, а мне нужно свайпить сами слайды

```js
$(".slider-in").slick({
 dots: true,
});

$(".single-item").slick({
 dots: true,
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #333;
  background: #419be0;
}

.slick-slide {
  text-align: center;
  color: #419be0;
  background: white;
}

.slider-in {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='single-item'>
    <div class='slider-in'>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-in'>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class='slider-in'>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a2af9a30/

Answer (score 1):

Нужно отключить свайп у внешнего слайдера:

```
$(".slider-in").slick({
    dots: true
});

$(".single-item").slick({
    dots: true,
    swipe: false
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a2af9a30/1/

Comment: Так слайды не свайпятся "мне нужно свайпить сами слайды"

Comment: это запрещает свайпить вообщем, а мне нужно свайпить слайды

Comment: Я так понял вы хотите свайпить только вложенные слайды, одновременно и те и другие не получится стандартными настройками, надо дописывать

Comment: да именно это мне и нужно, только не знаю как и что прописать

Comment: Так, я в комментарии написал о двух вариантах, какой именно?

Answer (score 0):

На [оф сайте](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) нашел свойство asNavFor
Type: string
Default: null
Set the slider to be the navigation of other slider (Class or ID Name)
Может поможет

Comment: нет, так не работает

Comment: @ЛёхаЩербинин есть такой вариант - в slick можно сделать несколько строк и вертикальные свайпы. Будет один слайдер, только еще со свайпами вверх и вниз